# C# Lambda Expression To Replace String Values In String Array

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I am trying to use .net 4.0 lambda methodology to remove double quotes (") around items in an array.   Here is the code I have, however, this does not seem to work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
string[] sa = new string[] { "\"Hello\"", "\"Goodbye\"", "\"Moshi\"", "\"Adios\"" };

// Trying to replace the 
Array.ForEach(sa, s => s.Replace("\"", "")); // Doesn't remove the quotes surrounding the string "Hello".
foreach(var s in sa)
   Console.WriteLine(s);
```

This still does not get rid of the " around the items.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no lambda expression that could be plugged into `ForEach` to accomplish your goal, because the action a lambda could take has no write access to the element, and the `string` itself is *immutable*.

What you can do is replacing the whole array, like this:

```
sa = sa.Select(s => s.Replace("\"", "")).ToArray();
```

This approach works, because it replaces the entire `sa` array with a newly created array that is based on `sa`'s elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq:

```
sa = sa.Select(s => s.Replace("\"", "")).ToArray();
```

OR use for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < sa.Length; i++)
    {
        sa[i] = sa[i].Replace("\"", "");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The other answers are what you should do if you want a *new* array out of some processing you perform on it's items.

However, if you don't (need a new array), and want to perform an [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) on each item of the array (which is what [`Array.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.foreach?view=netframework-4.7.2) does), you could do:

```
//This is pretty much what your code is trying to do
Array.ForEach(sa, i => Console.WriteLine(i.Replace("\"", "")));
```